# Access deprecated attribute "validation_data" in tf.keras.callbacks.Callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I decided to switch from keras to tf.keras (as recommended [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/)). Therefore I installed `tf.__version__=2.0.0` and `tf.keras.__version__=2.2.4-tf`. In an older version of my code (using some older Tensorflow version `tf.__version__=1.x.x`) I used a callback to compute custom metrics on the entire validation data at the end of each epoch. The idea to do so was taken from [here](https://medium.com/@thongonary/how-to-compute-f1-score-for-each-epoch-in-keras-a1acd17715a2).  However, it seems as if the "validation_data" attribute is deprecated so that the following code is not working any longer.

```
class ValMetrics(Callback):

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):

        self.val_all_mse = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):

        val_predict = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
        val_targ = self.validation_data[1]

        val_epoch_mse = mse_score(val_targ, val_predict)

        self.val_epoch_mse.append(val_epoch_mse)

        # Add custom metrics to the logs, so that we can use them with
        # EarlyStop and csvLogger callbacks
        logs["val_epoch_mse"] = val_epoch_mse

        print(f"\nEpoch: {epoch + 1}")
        print("-----------------")
        print("val_mse:     {:+.6f}".format(val_epoch_mse))

        return
```

My current workaround is the following. I simply gave validation_data as an argument to the `ValMetrics` class :

```
class ValMetrics(Callback):

    def __init__(self, validation_data):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.X_val, self.y_val = validation_data
```

Still I have some questions: Is the "validation_data" attribute really deprecated or can it be found elsewhere? Is there a better way to access the validation data at the end of each epoch than with the above workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm getting the same error

Comment: No, I'm still using the workaround described above. Sry

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

You are right that the argument, `validation_data` is deprecated as per [Tensorflow Callbacks Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback).

The issue which you are facing has been raised in Github. Related issues are [Issue1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10472), [Issue2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32981) and [Issue3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36375).

None of the above Github Issues is resolved and Your workaround of passing `Validation_Data` as an argument to Custom Callback is a good one, as per this [Github Comment](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10472#issuecomment-472543538), as many people found it useful.

Specifying the code of workaround below, for the benefit of the `Stackoverflow Community`, even though it is present in Github.

```
class Metrics(Callback):

    def __init__(self, val_data, batch_size = 20):
        super().__init__()
        self.validation_data = val_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        print(self.validation_data)
        self.val_f1s = []
        self.val_recalls = []
        self.val_precisions = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        batches = len(self.validation_data)
        total = batches * self.batch_size

        val_pred = np.zeros((total,1))
        val_true = np.zeros((total))

        for batch in range(batches):
            xVal, yVal = next(self.validation_data)
            val_pred[batch * self.batch_size : (batch+1) * self.batch_size] = np.asarray(self.model.predict(xVal)).round()
            val_true[batch * self.batch_size : (batch+1) * self.batch_size] = yVal

        val_pred = np.squeeze(val_pred)
        _val_f1 = f1_score(val_true, val_pred)
        _val_precision = precision_score(val_true, val_pred)
        _val_recall = recall_score(val_true, val_pred)

        self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
        self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall)
        self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision)

        return
```

I will keep following the Github Issues mentioned above and will update the Answer accordingly.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!