# Error while using custom metrics with multi-class classificaiton with Keras

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using custom mertrics for a multi-class classification task. I am using the code i found on internet.

The class for custom metrics is:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score

class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    self.confusion = []
    self.precision = []
    self.recall = []
    self.f1s = []

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    score = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
    predict =  
    np.round(np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0])))
    targ = self.validation_data[1]

    self.f1s.append(sklm.f1_score(targ, predict,average='micro'))
self.confusion.append(sklm.confusion_matrix(targ.argmax(axis=1),predict.argmax(axis=1)))

    return confusion, precision, recall, f1s
```

While using the object of class Metrics in model.fit:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, np.array(Y_train), 
       batch_size=32, 
       epochs=10,
       validation_data=(X_test, np.array(Y_test)), 
       #validation_split=0.1, 
       verbose=2,
       callbacks=[Metrics()])
```

I encountered the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Traceback:

```
 Epoch 1/10
        --------------------------------------------------------------

        TypeError                          Traceback (most recent call last)

        <ipython-input-63-1a11cfdbd329> in <module>()
             6                     #validation_split=0.1,
             7                     verbose=2,
       ----> 8                     callbacks=[Metrics()])

        3 frames

        <ipython-input-62-8073719b4ec0> in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
             12 
             13     def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        ---> 14         score =       
        np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
             15         predict =  
        np.round(np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0])))
             16         targ = self.validation_data[1]

        TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any idea why it's a NoneType object although I am giving the return parameters in the class methods?

Update:

I believe that the problem might be with the dataset i am using and the structure of the data might be causing the errors with the custom metrics. However, there is one solution that seems to work with my data.

```
 import keras.backend as K

 def f1_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    f1_val = 2*(precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon())
    return f1_val

 model.compile(...,metrics=['accuracy', f1_metric])
```

source:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48246/how-to-compute-f1-in-tensorflow

Comment: Could you add the full Traceback?

Comment: Are you using `tf` >= 2 or < 2 ?

Comment: tf is greater than 2

Comment: If you found this code on the internet, please provide the source.

Comment: The problem may not come with a custom metric, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `validaiton_data` is deprecated, [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080646/access-deprecated-attribute-validation-data-in-tf-keras-callbacks-callback). Here is a workaround for your set up.

```py
class Metrics(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self,val_x, val_y, batch_size = 20):
        super().__init__()
        self.val_x = val_x # < ---------
        self.val_y = val_y # < ---------
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
         ...
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        ...
```

Basically, you need to use `__init__` in your custom callback function.

### Sample Code

A demonstration is given below

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# train set / data 
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255

# validation set / data 
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

# train set / target 
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
# validation set / target 
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)  
# (50000, 32, 32, 3) (50000, 10)
# (10000, 32, 32, 3) (10000, 10)
```

### Model

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,3))
# Block 1
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, activation="relu")(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)

# Now that we apply global max pooling.
gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

# Finally, we add a classification layer.
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(gap)

# bind all
func_model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)
```

### Custom Callback

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, confusion_matrix

class Metrics(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self,val_x, val_y, batch_size = 20):
        super().__init__()
        self.val_x = val_x
        self.val_y = val_y
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.confusion = []
        self.precision = []
        self.recall = []
        self.f1s = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        x    = self.val_x
        targ = self.val_y

        score   = np.asarray(self.model.predict(x))
        predict = np.round(np.asarray(self.model.predict(x)))
        self.f1s.append(f1_score(targ, predict, average='micro'))
        self.confusion.append(confusion_matrix(targ.argmax(axis=1), predict.argmax(axis=1)))
        print("\nAt epoch {} f1_score {}:".format(epoch, self.f1s[-1]))
        print('\nAt epoch {} cm {}'.format(epoch, self.confusion[-1]))
        return
```

### Run

```
# compile
print('\nFunctional API')
func_model.compile(
          loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
          )

metrics = Metrics(x_test, y_test)

# fit 
func_model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
               validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
               callbacks= [metrics] , 
               batch_size=128, epochs=3)
```

**Log**

```
Train on 50000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/3
49920/50000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.7155
At epoch 0 f1_score 0.14721851357365376:
At epoch 0 cm [[919  11   2   0   0   2   3   6  46  11]
 [859  98   0   0   0   0   2   2   5  34]
 [942   7   9   0   1   6  27   6   2   0]
 [973   6   1   1   0   8   5   3   2   1]
 [949   1   0   0  22   1  22   3   1   1]
 [958   2   0   0   0  26   5   6   2   1]
 [831   2   3   0   0   1 158   1   3   1]
 [916   5   1   0   1   6   2  56   1  12]
 [750  11   0   0   0   0   1   4 227   7]
 [835  27   0   0   0   1   4   4   9 120]]
50000/50000 [==============================] - 10s 206us/sample - loss: 1.7154 - val_loss: 1.7113
Epoch 2/3
49664/50000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.7102
At epoch 1 f1_score 0.16048514677447706:
At epoch 1 cm [[896  10   2   0   0   2   2   5  69  14]
 [845  89   0   0   0   1   2   2  11  50]
 [941   6  12   0   2   7  23   5   4   0]
 [967   5   1   0   0  13   6   2   5   1]
 [946   0   1   0  27   1  20   2   2   1]
 [945   2   1   0   0  38   5   5   2   2]
 [840   2   4   0   0   1 148   1   3   1]
 [910   4   1   0   1  13   1  51   1  18]
 [694   6   0   0   0   0   0   3 290   7]
 [803  23   0   0   1   1   4   4  13 151]]
50000/50000 [==============================] - 10s 198us/sample - loss: 1.7102 - val_loss: 1.7080
Epoch 3/3
50000/50000 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.7059
At epoch 2 f1_score 0.16229953553588644:
At epoch 2 cm [[899   9   2   0   0   2   3   5  65  15]
 [861  72   0   0   0   0   2   1  11  53]
 [935   4  10   0   1   5  36   6   3   0]
 [972   4   1   2   0   6   8   1   4   2]
 [949   0   1   0  10   0  35   2   2   1]
 [963   2   1   0   0  19   6   5   2   2]
 [796   2   4   0   0   0 194   0   3   1]
 [917   3   1   0   0   3   3  53   1  19]
 [702   4   0   0   0   0   1   3 281   9]
 [798  20   0   0   0   1   5   4  13 159]]
50000/50000 [==============================] - 10s 196us/sample - loss: 1.7059 - val_loss: 1.7067
```

### Update

With your concern with custom metrics, it works fine

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def f1_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    f1_val = 2*(precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon())
    return f1_val

# compile
print('\nFunctional API')
func_model.compile(
          metrics=['accuracy', f1_metric],
          loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
          )
```

```
Epoch 1/3
50000/50000 [==============================] - ETA: 5s - loss: 2.2136 - accuracy: 0.1976 - f1_metric: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.1119 - val_accuracy: 0.2443 - val_f1_metric: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/3
50000/50000 [==============================] -  ETA: 7s - loss: 2.0456 - accuracy: 0.2546 - f1_metric: 4.3617e-04 - val_loss: 1.9909 - val_accuracy: 0.2829 - val_f1_metric: 0.0022
```

Comment: Thanks @M.Innat for a detailed answer. I am getting the error "ValueError: unknown is not supported" It looks like something is wroing with the format of the data i am giving to fit..

Comment: Please update your new situation with details in your question.

Comment: Is your code works without these custom `callbacks`? Can you ensure that the `sklearn` libraries are getting the correct shape of your input?

Comment: I have to check it as i only tested it with accuracy metric available with keras and different custom metrics without sklearn.

Comment: Yes that is what i said in my update that the example i provided in the update is working with my data and the problem might be with the data format i am giving to model.fit. The task is a sequene labeling task so that might be the reason that the custom metrics you provided is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

The Keras code version that you are using is not compatible with the actual version of Keras and TensorFlow, this is why you get `None` on the `validation set` object, as Pedro correctly pointed out.

If you are looking for an exact way to calculate the metrics on the validation set, please consult my accepted answer here:

[How to get other metrics in Tensorflow 2.0 (not only accuracy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616842/how-to-get-other-metrics-in-tensorflow-2-0-not-only-accuracy/60800425#60800425)

Comment: Thanks a lot. As i tried many possible ways with my data but there was always an error and i believe the error is either with the dataset or with versions. I will try the answer in the link you posted.

Comment: Please tell me, it should work, otherwise we will make it work.

Comment: Normally it should work with very small modifications... the report dictionary contains all the metrics that you need for your case.

Comment: Thanks @Timbus Calin. The error in line  "y_pred = self.model.predict(self.test_data))' is invalid syntax. I

Comment: Is it possible that you copy-pasted and the lines of code are shifted a little bit?

Comment: I reviewed my answer and indeed the lines were shifted a little bit to the right but this should prevent you from having a running code, since you can fix it very qiuickly

Comment: No i checked it. I am using Colab so let me disconnect the session start a new one as sometimes Colab does give strange errors when u run the cells individually.

Comment: Very odd indeed.

Comment: The code should work, I tested it on my own machine and the one who asked the question confirmed it works, so there is something odd that is going on.

Comment: Actually i corrected the lines before running it because if the lines are shifted the error you usually get is unexpected indent.

Comment: Right, so there is an issue then with the adaptation to your problem.

Comment: I wanted to say that there was no indentation problem as i spotted it while copying your code and you are absolutely right its odd but i am still getting same invalid syntax error which does not make any sense. Any way thanks a lot and i found another solution for just f1_score which is working.

Answer (score 0):

`validation_data` is None.
Looking at the keras source code, I can see the member initialised to None in the Callback **init** method but I never see it being assigned.

Comment: my test data is my validation data because i am not using separate test data according to the requirements and i am not using train_test split method to split the dataset as the data is already divided into train and test sets.